# CSS input effect not working if required is removed

Tags: html, css

The label effect will work if required is there in input tag. But the effect will not work if i remove the required attribute [Click to see working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rahul_Patel_S_G/sy83j3q2/4/)
Is there any solution for this.

> html

```
<div class="group ">
<input type="text" required="" class="module-input" />
<label >Name</label>
</div>
```

Snippet:

```css
.module-input {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  display: block;
  width: 97%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #94a3a9;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #5a686d;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}


/* LABEL */

label {
  color: #94a3a9;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0.5%;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}


/* active state */

input:focus+label,
input:valid+label {
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #94a3a9;
}
```

```html
<div class="group ">
  <input type="text" class="module-input" />
  <label>Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: What effect? Include all relevant code in your question. You've just shown the markup. Where is the CSS? Do not link to external sites, show what you have in the question itself.

Comment: go to fiddle u will get css

Comment: Rahul, that is what I said. You should not force people to go to external sites. Include all relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: ok this won't happen next time

Comment: Thanks @jones for the edit.

Comment: Have upvoted. Actually a good question this is, especially now that it is complete.

Comment: thank you for that @Abhitalks:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140173/discussion-between-rahul-patel-and-abhitalks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the CSS as `input:valid ~ label` Which means: put the label on top if the input is valid.

When you remove the `required` attribute, the input becomes valid by default. So without the `required` attribute, the label effect wont work by default.

You should use something like `input[required]:valid ~ label`

Comment: A better way would be to use CSS3 selectors. Define your styles on `input:required:valid + label, input:focus + label {...`. i.e. use the `:required` selector along with `:valid`. This allows you to fluidly chain the style on different types of input constraints. e.g. `input:in-range` or `input:out-of-range` or `input:optional` etc.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/Rahul_Patel_S_G/sy83j3q2/24/ if i type a value and if i focus it to another text box the css will not work.

Comment: @rahulpatel: That is not possible with CSS. You will JS for that. Reason = `:empty` selector does not work with `input`s.

Comment: ya i debugged the focusout problem through JS, but when i assign a value to a input from angular the label effect will not work. any solution for that??

Comment: @rahulpatel would you post your final code so people like me happy cause i got bugs with someone solution in bellow

Answer (score 6):

If you update the rule with the attribute selector, `input[required]:valid ~ label`, this it will work, both with and without the `required` attribute

What happens is when an `input` does not have the `reqiured` attribute it is considered valid, hence the rule kick in immediately.

*Updated*

To be able to handle this properly, since `:empty` won't work on `input` elements, I added a small script and an attribute selector, which being set on a change and then the CSS rule check if it's empty

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var inp = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    inp[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      this.setAttribute("data-value", this.value);
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.module-input {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  display: block;
  width: 97%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #94a3a9;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #5a686d;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}


/* LABEL */

label {
  color: #94a3a9;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0.5%;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}


/* active state */

input[data-value]:not([data-value=""]) ~ label,
input:focus ~ label {
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #94a3a9;
}
```

```html
<div class="group ">
  <input type="text" class="module-input" required="" />
  <label>Name</label>
</div>
<div class="group ">
  <input type="text" class="module-input" />
  <label>Address</label>
</div>
```

Comment: type a value in address and focus to another input field.. the label will come down

Comment: @rahulpatel Updated my answer

Comment: `$(".group input").focusout(function(){
   if($(this).val() != ""){
    $(this).addClass("has-content");
   }else{
    $(this).removeClass("has-content");
   }
  });`  and in css `input:focus ~ label, input[required]:valid ~ label,.has-content.module-input ~ label {...}` will do the trick

Comment: @rahulpatel That will most likely work too, I just trust the `change` event more than the `focusout` ... :)

Comment: Cross browser support ??

Comment: @rahulpatel All and from IE9 ... do you need IE8?

Comment: no just a clarification thank u :)

Comment: @LGSon i just put js without load or even not loading doesn't work, please check mine in here http://jsfiddle.net/kqxyhagf/

Comment: @FreddySidauruk Just did...works just fine, so how does it not work for you? .. Which browser do you use?

Comment: @LGSon    Hey thanks for your response, i just forgot to load js when DOM is ready, by the way i have input type which is value from cookie, if exist then i put in it, but the label doesn't move, demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/dauruk0512/bndqjca5/2/

Comment: @FreddySidauruk You sample doesn't work on load as the custom attribute `data-value` isn't there yet, it gets added when someone add a value (change the value and you'll see it works). A solution for your case would be to instead use the standard `value` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/85dxs34z/

Comment: @FreddySidauruk The standard `value` attribute never gets change on user input, it always holds what is given to it when markup is rendered, hence use it in CSS won't work by default. My small script change that and update it with the user input and make it possible to target with CSS.

Comment: @FreddySidauruk I also now closed the question with a later answer of mine, one I just remembered, which show how-to with the standard `value` attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333727/simulation-of-a-placeholder

Comment: @LGSon i found bug, let say i have pages register and login while user in pages login, they click href goes to register when they typing effect place holder doesn't work, please last question cause i'm trying change another method doesn't work at all

Comment: @FreddySidauruk Can't help with code I can't see. Post another e.g. jsfiddle showing the issue.

Comment: @LGSon that what i mean, is it polite post my real demo here ? so you can testing

Comment: @FreddySidauruk It is okay to post a fiddle demo here as I asked for one.

Comment: @LGSon fiddle doesn't allow create multiple pages, isn't it ?

Comment: @LGSon why in this demo work perfectly by the way i use nuxt https://plnkr.co/edit/nYjRaTox3A1NqNaUJ1A6?p=preview

Comment: @FreddySidauruk You can't use an `<a href='login.html'>` like that. It won't submit the form. You need an `<input type='submit' />` and all inputs wrapped in a `<form>`, and the button you can style like a link if you want, e.g. like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/LQNtba6eEZWrdy4Ujp6n?p=preview

Comment: @FreddySidauruk And for me labels work just fine, moving back and forth if there is a value, either at load or when typing.

Comment: @LGSon i have problem when user typing in register then i move bye clicking register the labels doesn't work that's why i put link not submit button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184760/discussion-between-freddy-sidauruk-and-lgson).

Answer (score 1):

When you don't place required, the `input:valid ~ label` properties in css are used because your input is not required, so it is valid

Comment: Got it thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove tilde ~ sign from valid

```
input:focus~label,
input:valid label {
top: -8px;
font-size: 12px;
color: #94a3a9;
}
```

after this doesn't matter using Required or not.