# Change ui-select-match placeholder text styles

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have next element with `placeholder`:

```
<ui-select-match placeholder="My hint">
    {{$someItem}}
</ui-select-match>
```

and I need to change `placeholder`'s text style to `bold`, `italic`, etc.
I am new in css, so not sure how to do it in a proper way.

Comment: Here is a cross browser workaround I made: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44333787/2827823

Comment: Check this post answer in a similar question to understand more and adjust your css code to be recognised in all browsers [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: thanks, that's works for me

Answer (score 3):

You can use pseudo code but be aware this is not standardized. For more information have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/).

```css
input::placeholder {
  color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="test">
```

Comment: I do not see any CSS there

Comment: Try this and you can see no change in `placeholder` text - `ui-select-match::placeholder {
  color: darkorange;
}`

Comment: Obviously not, because that code is wrong. Without the first placeholder word you may have more luck. Right now i am driving and typing which is not a good combination so I will look at it later

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
.ui-select-placeholder{
  color:pink;
}
```

Thanks!