# Input length greater than 0 not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write some code that if the input is empty the input color changes to red. After user types in input, the red color is removed.

Html

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- add main style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <!-- add JQuery -->
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="financeContainer">
    <div class="searchBox">
        <input id="financeSearch" type="text" class="financeInput" placeholder="Enter The Code">
        <button id="financeBtn" class="financeSearchBt"><i class="fas fa-search financeSearchIcon"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Css

```
.redColor{
    color: red;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#financeSearch").keydown(function () {
        if ($("#financeSearch").val().length>0){
            $("#financeSearch").removeClass("redColor")
        }
    });
    $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            $('#financeBtn').trigger('click');
        }
    });
    $("#financeBtn").click(function () {
        var financeKey = $("#financeSearch").val();
        if (financeKey == ""){
            $("#financeSearch").addClass("redColor")
        }
});
```

When the button is submitted the input gets the class redColor.and I expect if the user types the red color is removed. But after typing 2 characters it's being done. I want it after the first character typed to be done.

Comment: With a tiny script you can solve this very elegant using CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333727/simulation-of-a-placeholder/44333787#44333787

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `keydown` is called the last entered character is not yet added to the value of input. So thats why you need to enter two characters to remove red color.

You should use `keyup` instead of `keydown`

You don't need to select `$("#financeSearch")` inside the event handler just use `$(this)`.

And also no need to compare the `length` greater than `0`. You can directly put `$(this).val().length` because all values other than `0` in numbers are truthy.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#financeSearch").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length) {
      $(this).removeClass("redColor")
    }
  });
  $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $('#financeBtn').trigger('click');
    }
  });
  $("#financeBtn").click(function() {
    var financeKey = $("#financeSearch").val();
    if (financeKey == "") {
      $("#financeSearch").addClass("redColor")
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.redColor {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- add JQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="financeContainer">
  <div class="searchBox">
    <input id="financeSearch" type="text" class="financeInput" placeholder="Enter The Code">
    <button id="financeBtn" class="financeSearchBt"><i class="fas fa-search financeSearchIcon"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (cough) you should rather use `input` event.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do it all with CSS and a single HTML attribute.
Also note that at least in Chrome, to target the placeholder's color, you need to do it explicitely in CSS

```css
:invalid, :invalid::placeholder {
  color: red;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="financeContainer">
  <div class="searchBox">

    <input id="financeSearch" type="text" class="financeInput" placeholder="Enter The Code"
    required ><!-- add this attribute -->
    
    <button id="financeBtn" class="financeSearchBt"><i class="fas fa-search financeSearchIcon"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if what you want is really just to set the color of this placeholder, then you don't even need this HTML attribute:

```css
#financeSearch::placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="financeContainer">
  <div class="searchBox">

    <input id="financeSearch" type="text" class="financeInput" placeholder="Enter The Code">
    
    <button id="financeBtn" class="financeSearchBt"><i class="fas fa-search financeSearchIcon"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```